# protocolでEquatableを継承する方法

Tags: swift

以下のようにEquatableを継承したプロトコルを扱いたいですがコンパイルエラーになってしまいます。
どうすればいいでしょうか

```
protocol Hoge: Equatable {
    var name: String { get }
}

class HogeA: Hoge {
    static func ==(lhs: HogeA, rhs: HogeA) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }

    let name = UUID().uuidString
}

class HogeB: Hoge {
    static func ==(lhs: HogeB, rhs: HogeB) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }

    let name = UUID().uuidString
}

let hogeA1 = HogeA()
let array: [Hoge] = [HogeA(), HogeB(), hogeA1] // コンパイルエラー Protocol 'Hoge' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associ
array.index(of: hogeA1) // 2が返ってきてほしい
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

エラーメッセージにある通り、Swiftでは`Self`や関連型を持つprotocolを普通の型のように変数のデータ型や配列の要素型としては使うことはできません。

`Equatable`プロトコルは、

```
public protocol Equatable {
    public static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
}
```

のように定義されており、もろに`Self`が使われていますから、`Equatable`や`Equatable`を継承したprotocolを普通の型のように使うことはできません。

そもそもなぜそのようことが禁止されているかを考えるには、あなたのコードは丁度良いでしょう。

```
let array: [Hoge] = [HogeA(), HogeB(), hogeA1]
```

このようなコードが許されたとすると、次の行は処理できなくなってしまいます。

```
array.index(of: hogeA1)
```

`HogeA`に定義された`==`は`HogeA`と`HogeA`を比較するもの、`HogeB`に定義された`==`は`HogeB`と`HogeB`を比較するものです。したがって`hogeA1`と`HogeB()`は比較できないと言うことになります。

---

あなたの例ならば、`Hoge`から`Equatable`を外してしまうと言うのが一つの解決方法でしょう。

```
protocol Hoge {
    var name: String { get }
}

//`HogeA`, `HogeB`クラスの定義は同じで良い

let hogeA1 = HogeA()
let array: [Hoge] = [HogeA(), HogeB(), hogeA1]
if let index = array.index(where: {$0.name == hogeA1.name}) {
    print(index) //->2
} else {
    print("Not Found")
}
```